# MyError Code: 1093. You can't specify target table

Tags: mysql, error-code

I am working on a problem in which I have to use the table I want to update in a subquery. Can you help me find a solution?

```
UPDATE employees_clients AS ec2
SET ec2.employee_id = (CASE WHEN ec2.client_id = ec2.employee_id
 THEN (SELECT e.id
 FROM clients AS c
 JOIN employees_clients AS ec
 ON ec.client_id = c.id
 JOIN employees AS e
 ON e.id = ec.employee_id
 GROUP BY e.id
 ORDER BY count(e.id),e.id
 LIMIT 1)
 END);
```

Error Code: 1093. You can't specify target table 'ec2' for update in FROM clause

I found a solution to the problem I created a virtual table.

```
    CREATE VIEW v_employee_with_min_clients AS
    SELECT e.id
    FROM clients AS c
    JOIN employees_clients AS ec
    ON ec.client_id = c.id
    JOIN employees AS e
    ON e.id = ec.employee_id
    GROUP BY e.id
    ORDER BY count(e.id),e.id
    LIMIT 1;

SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;
UPDATE employees_clients AS ecl
SET ecl.employee_id = (SELECT * FROM v_employee_with_min_clients)
WHERE ecl.client_id = ecl.employee_id;
```

Comment: I tried the work around with SELECT SELECT still same error code

Comment: Read Reference Manual, UPDATE syntax, pay attention to multiple-table syntax.